# Javascript and the Web

Tags: javascript, user-interface, web

I hope this question is appropriate to be asked Here. Okay I've been wondering ever since i started web development, since much of the web experience is highly dependent on Javascript,Why is there still an option to disable it in the settings? Doesn't this break most of the modern web Apps today on the web? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/138865/htg-explains-should-you-disable-javascript/)

> Many people who disable JavaScript do it because of a perceived security benefit. There have been a few browser vulnerabilities that were exploited via JavaScript. However, this is extremely uncommon and the rare security holes in JavaScript engines have been patched very quickly. Most websites use JavaScript – it’s what makes the web we have today possible.
>
> [...]
>
> Disabling JavaScript also prevents some types of ads from loading. We don’t encourage blocking ads, but if you must, there are better ways to do so than disabling JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Following are some facts about javascripts

1. One of the most common errors is HTML injection, allowing third
   parties to inject JavaScript into your security context. That allows
   an attacker to control what a user does on your site, completely
   breaking account security.
2. Example : One prime example is [FredsCars](http://FredsCars.net), a popular car auction site that was turned into a small static html page simply because they couldn't control the site's behavior due to the JavaScript vulnerabilities...
3. As javascript can be dynamic and executed remotely, another factor to look into to maintain security with javascript is the code itself. Is part or all of the code remotely executed on another domain? If so it is important to be aware of when these domains expire if they are trusted or to make sure that these domains are authoritative. Third party javascript code, widgets and also ad servers usually execute code off another domain and can be easily manipulated to exploit the website if the domain is later possessed by another owner.
4. Javascript security is mainly related to phishing attacks intended to trick users to divulge credit card information and other financial and personal data; this is mainly done using the redirection function in Javascript. Fortunately, in current times, with the sophisticated security measures provided by leading web browsers like Mozilla's Firefox, Javascript is slowly taking the backseat as far as security threats are concerned while spyware and other techniques are used to exploit Internet users.
5. Ad servers use javascript to display ads on websites, ads are virtually bread and butter to the website publisher and is thus responsible to several successful, established and useful websites. Apart from ads Javascript is also used to add graphical effects as well as several other functions to websites.

Comment: Thanks Khamar for the elaborate explanation

Answer (score 1):

That's the **advantage** part you are talking about.

If you look into the  **disadvantages** you will understand why this option still exists.

- `In which the major issue is to exploit user system`

  **Ex:** Continuous loop javascript may freeze your browser which may lead to system crash
- `Generating several popups for unwanted ads that may lead to malware
     or untrusted sites`

You can use some below references for knowledge

[Pros and cons](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/pros-cons.html)

[Disadvantages of javascript](http://www.jscripters.com/javascript-advantages-and-disadvantages/)